# specify Maximum number of backups in the repository in pleskbackup

Tags: plesk

I have set up a custom back up of my VPS server.

/usr/local/psa/bin/pleskbackup server --prefix="VPS" --skip-logs --exclude-domain=mydomain.eu --output-file=ftp://myotherdomain.com/VPS-Backup/ --ftp-login=username --ftp-password=************* --ftp-passive-mode

And I have made this a scheduled task in the Plesk Admin.

All good.

How/Where do I specify the 'Maximum number of backups in the repository' so that the Back Ups don't stack up in the myotherdomain.com account.

Can I do so by adding an instruction to the command above or through Plesk?

Answer (score 0):

Look at server_pref utility with option -max-backup-files